# Significance of metric tensor on abstract manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

In the 4-D curved manifold of spacetime in general relativity, the metric tensor generalizes the spacetime distance of Minkowski space. But how about in an abstract manifold? It would still be (0,2) rank tensor. But what is the significance of the metric tensor defined on a non-geometric abstract manifold, say, a set of differential equations.

Comment: So honestly, not my field of expertise, so I'm not sure I can give you a good answer, but the phrase non-geometric manifold sounds like a contradiction in terms. Particularly if you have a metric on it. Manifolds *are* geometric, and metrics on them refine that geometry and make it more rich. At least to my understanding so far.

Comment: I would say a metric exactly *is* a choice of geometry - by endowing a smooth manifold with a metric, you take a topological object and endow it with the structure of length, angle, etc.

Comment: @jgon: An abstract manifold is a topological space with an atlas of coordinate charts.  Consider now two charts. In the overlap between them, if there  is  no  way to  switch from  one  to  another to obtain a global covering of the manifold, we talk about non geometric manifolds.